# Type-safe pattern for modifying individual properties in Typescript interface

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript interface that includes properties that are a type union, and I have a predefined way of modifying the value of the property at runtime that narrows the type.  As a simple example:

```
interface WideFoo {
  x: string | RegExp;
  y: number;
}

interface NarrowFoo {
  x: RegExp;
  y: number;
}

function narrow(wf: WideFoo): NarrowFoo {
  return {
    x: wf.x instanceof RegExp ? wf.x : new RegExp(wf.x),
    y: wf.y,
  };
}

function f(nf: NarrowFoo) {
  if (nf.x.test("Hello")) { ... }
}

declare const wf: WideFoo;
f(narrow(wf));
```

The `narrow` function makes a new object and copies over the property, converting it if necessary.  This is easy when I know exactly what properties to copy, and the interface is small.  If the interface is large or complex, this approach scales poorly.

I can't have type-directed runtime code (that's a core TS principle), so I don't think I can automatically pick which properties need to be converted.  I don't want to use casts or type assertions, because I want the code to fail loudly if a new property is added to the interface that needs to be converted at runtime.

How can I write `narrow` so that properties that won't be modified are copied/preserved, while properties that are of the "wide" type are converted and correctly limited to the narrower type?  It's OK if the solution only works for flat (one-deep) objects, rather than recursively.

Comment: please provide more test cases of what you expect. DO you expect argument of `narrow` to be the object which always has `x` and `y`?

Comment: The usual way of saying "copy everything but overwrite these specific properties" would be `{...wf, x: wf.x instanceof RegExp ? wf.x : new RegExp(wf.x)}`. This will keep working without needing any changes if you add more properties to `WideFoo` which don't need to be narrowed. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I tend to avoid object destructuring because that was the one modern-ES feature that always used to bite me with legacy-Edge users.  (My application runs in a limited set of environments and I only had to support current Chrome+FF, and legacy Edge.)  We dropped legacy Edge a while ago so I'll try destructuring in this case, it sounds like a good fit.  If you want to make that an answer I could accept it.